# Arabic characters displays tangled incorrectly in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I am using Crystal Reports for VisualStudio v13.0.23 for Visual Studio 2017 and I am creating a report that is in Arabic language
Here is a screenshot of the right display (that’s when activating – in focus - the textbox for editing)

[image]

However, this wrong display appears when textbox loses focus

[image]

I tried using different fonts but the same result and I would like to mention that when printing the report, the display is correct with some displacements
So any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I usually use the Arial Font with Arabic letters,

Comment: If the problem persists try placing a Text Object then place the field in it.

Comment: It is already in Arial font as TextObject

Comment: Did you find any solution? the problem appears only in لا characters.